# How to configure Pyramid to find MongoDB Primary replica

Tags: python, mongodb, pyramid, pymongo

Is there a way to configure Pyramid so that when MongoDB fails over to a secondary replica, Pyramid starts using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pyramid should be using the official python MongoDB drivers. The drivers are configured to do this "automatically", but they need the correct connection string.

See [here](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/replica_set.html) for the connection strings.

One thing to keep in mind, the definition of "automatic fail-over" is not clear cut.

If you create a new connection to the DB that connection will point at the current primary.

If you use an existing connection from a pool, that connection may be pointing at the wrong server. In this case it will throw an exception the first time and should connect to the correct server the second time.

However, when a fail-over happens, there is a brief window where there is no primary (*typically 2-10 seconds*). If you use a connection during this period, no connection will be primary.

Note that this is not specific to python, it's the way Replica Sets function.

Comment: Thanks Gates VP.. I think it was the 2-10 seconds downtime that was throwing me.. Missed that example in the Pymongo docs too.  Cheers!

Comment: @MFB np on that 2-10 seconds. Honestly, it's not clearly documented on the MongoDB site itself and it's not specific to Python. They all throw exceptions for a couple of seconds, the tough thing is deciding the best course of action. Manual retry? Auto retry for 2 seconds then manual retry?

Comment: do  you know the correct syntax for the Pyramid ini file?  Mongodb URL = mongodb://xx.xx.xx.xx for single instance, but what about replica set?

Comment: You're looking for the following page, you need to put a comma between hosts: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Connections